# How to enable a javascript loop to recursively iterate an unknown number of times?

Tags: javascript, loops, design-patterns

I've run across a type of problem I'm not familiar with in javascript. I'm guessing there is likely a straightforward approach to solving this sort of problem, but I am unclear what it might be.

- I have an array which contains a series of objects.
- Each of those objects may (or may not) contain a deeper array which contains a series of objects.
- Each of *those* objects may (or may not) contain a deeper array which contains a series of objects
- (and so on...)

I need to process each object in each series of objects, so writing a `function` which runs a `for loop` which I can repeatedly invoke seems the obvious approach.

But... (here's the issue)... since the function may invoke *itself* a repeated number of times, how can I write a loop which keeps going deeper into the object, as deep as it needs to?

Here's an example...

With this object:

```
{
  "level1": [
    {
      "FirstItem": "one",
      "SecondItem": "two",
      "ThirdItem": [
        {
          "FirstItem": "three",
          "SecondItem": "four"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "FirstItem": "five",
      "SecondItem": "six",
      "ThirdItem": [
        {
          "FirstItem": "seven",
          "SecondItem": "eight"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can log the values in the right order using this nested loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(myObject.level1).length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < (Object.values(myObject.level1[i]).length); j++) {

        if (typeof Object.values(myObject.level1[i])[j] === 'string') {
            console.log(Object.values(myObject.level1[i])[j]);
        }

        else {

            for (var k = 0; k < Object.values(myObject.level1[i])[j].length; k++) {

                for (var l = 0; l < (Object.values(Object.values(myObject.level1[i])[j][k]).length); l++) {

                    if (typeof Object.values(Object.values(myObject.level1[i])[j][k])[l] === 'string') {
                    console.log(Object.values(Object.values(myObject.level1[i])[j][k])[l]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Proof:**

```js
var myObject = {};
myObject['level1'] = [];

myObject.level1[0] = {FirstItem: 'one', SecondItem: 'two'};
myObject.level1[0]['ThirdItem'] = [];

myObject.level1[1] = {FirstItem: 'five', SecondItem: 'six'};
myObject.level1[1]['ThirdItem'] = [];

myObject.level1[0].ThirdItem[0] = {FirstItem: 'three', SecondItem: 'four'};
myObject.level1[1].ThirdItem[0] = {FirstItem: 'seven', SecondItem: 'eight'};

for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(myObject.level1).length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < (Object.values(myObject.level1[i]).length); j++) {

        if (typeof Object.values(myObject.level1[i])[j] === 'string') {
            console.log(Object.values(myObject.level1[i])[j]);
        }
    
        else {
            
            for (var k = 0; k < Object.values(myObject.level1[i])[j].length; k++) {
                 
                for (var l = 0; l < (Object.values(Object.values(myObject.level1[i])[j][k]).length); l++) {

                    if (typeof Object.values(Object.values(myObject.level1[i])[j][k])[l] === 'string') {
                    console.log(Object.values(Object.values(myObject.level1[i])[j][k])[l]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But... the loop is absolutely horrible. It's verbose and ugly. And, if it were required to go even deeper into the object, how on earth would it then come up with the iterators `m`, `n`, `o` and `p`?

I am guessing that another type of loop (like `while` or `do... while`) might be a better approach, but it's not clear to me how javascript can ascertain the depth of the object.

Ultimately, I am speculating that this is just an example of a pattern that I am unfamiliar with and I am using the wrong tools, awkwardly, to produce the right result.

Comment: The simple answer is "use a Recursive Function" - ie. https://www.sitepoint.com/recursion-functional-javascript/ Each recursive call will recieve a different object/collection (one of the child elements of the previous/parent call's "root" object) to work on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function printValues(inputObj) {
    for (var key in inputObj) {
        if (Array.isArray(inputObj[key])) {
            inputObj[key].forEach(function(currentObj) {
                printValues(currentObj);
            });
        } else {
            console.log(inputObj[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Superb, @Andrea - very impressive. `Array.isArray()` is new to me; I am aware of the `for in` loop for enumerating `objects` though I am still trying to get my head around it and I am familiar with `forEach`. You have written a very concise and elegant function - precisely the kind of thing I was trying to build. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a Tree (data structure). Trees are made up of parent and child nodes. The nodes each have a value, and some have a child property, which is an array of other nodes. I hope this link helps, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal.